# Import settings from the file

Tags: python, yaml

I would like to import settings from a yaml file, but make them available as regular variables in the current context.

for example I may have a file:

```
param1: 12345

param2: test11

param3:
    a: 4
    b: 7
    c: 9
```

And I would like to have variables `param1`, `param2`, `param3` in my code.

I may want to use this from any function and do not want to have them available globally.

I have heard about `locals()` and `globals()` functuons, but did not get how to use them for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `locals()['newvarname'] = 12345` to create a new variable.
And you can just read your file and fill in this structure as you'd like.

You may write a function to call it and import settings:

```
import sys
import yaml


def get_settings(filename):
    flocals = sys._getframe().f_back.f_locals  # get locals() from caller
    with open(filename, 'r') as ysfile:
        ydata = yaml.load(ysfile.read())
    for pname in ydata:
        # assume the yaml file contains dict
        flocals[pname] = ydata[pname]  # merge caller's locals with new vars
```

Comment: Wouldn't `update()` accomplish the same thing as your for loop?

Comment: Good point, in general - yes. But I have more extended code in my project where I also deal with sub-keys, just copied the function from sources and cut it..

Answer (score 0):

Even though the trick is great in @baldr's answer, I suggest moving the variable assignments out of the function for better readability. Having a function change its caller's context seems very hard to remember and maintain. So,

```
import yaml

def get_settings(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as yf:
        return yaml.load(yf.read())

def somewhere():
    locals().update(get_settings('foo.yaml'))
    print(param1)
```

Even then I would strongly suggest simply using the dictionary. Otherwise, you risk very strange bugs. For instance, what if your yaml file contains a `open` or a `print` key? They will override python's functions, so the `print(param1)` in the example will raise a `TypeError` exception.